# Display specific fields from a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I'm very new to PHP. I have looked around at other questions but none of them seem to provide a solution, so hopefully someone can help!

I have a csv file, but wish to pick out individual fields instead of displaying a whole column.

Is this possible with php?

My code so far (below) picks out specific columns which is not quite what I want to do. If it could pick out specific rows, that would be better than what it's currently showing, but ideally I'd be able to pick specific fields out.

```
             <table>
                <?php
                    $handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
                    while (!feof($handle) ) {
                        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",");
                        print "<tr><td>" . $line_of_text[0] . "</td><td>" . $line_of_text[5] . "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                ?>
             </table>
```

Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: There is no interface to translate your wishes in PHP code yet. You have at least to verbalize conditions to use to filter your data out

Comment: How do you decide which rows you want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgetcsv() only reads the file line by line, so if you want to skip to a particular line, you'd have to put that in yourself:

```
$desired_line = 17;
$current_line = 0;

while($line = fgetcsv($handle)) {
   $current_line++;
   if ($current_line < $desired_line) {
      continue; // keep reading more lines until we reach 17.
   }
   print blah blah blah;
}
```

Comment: H Mark,thanks for your reply. This didn't seem to work though, just showed a load of whatever number I but in 'desired_line'.

This was my code - I'm sure I've gone wrong somewhere!

`$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
     
     $desired_line = 1;
     $current_line = 0;
     
     while ($line = fgetcsv($handle) ) {
      $current_line++;
      if ($current_line < $desired_line) {
        continue; // keep reading more lines until we reach 17.
         }

      print "<tr><td>" . $desired_line . "</td></tr>";
     }
     fclose($handle);`

Comment: you'd want `print "<tr><td>{$line[some field # here]}</td></tr>";` instead. `$line` is the array of data you just read from the csv. `$desired_line` is one of the control variables.